# tuple index error while doing regression fit

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, tuples, linear-regression

I'm writing a code to do linear single variate regression analysis of data using numpy. I know that fit() function in Python uses np.array() but the program is throwing me tuple index error and I'm at my wit's end now. Here is my code:

```
def linear_model_main(X_parameter, Y_parameter, prediction_value):
regression = linear_model.LinearRegression()
regression.fit(X_parameter, Y_parameter, prediction_value)
prediction_outcome = regression.predict(prediction_value)
predictions = {}
predictions['intercept'] = regression.intercept_
predictions['coefficient'] = regression.coef_
predictions['predicted_value'] = prediction_outcome
return predictions

X, Y = get_data(filename)
Xarr = np.array(X)
Yarr = np.array(Y)
predictionvalue = 70
result = linear_model_main(Xarr, Yarr, predictionvalue)
```

Xarr and Yarr are np.arrays of separate columns of data taken from a csv file and are basically the X and Y coordinate values in the regression. When printed, they look this:

```
[  7.  73.  49. ...,  56.  56.  56.]
[ 5863.  5860.  5860. ...,  5860.  5860.  5860.]
```

It is a huge dataset (about 130,000 rows and 35 columns).

Comment: Please, show the full exception traceback in order that we can see the faulty line.

Comment: Why would you put pridiction_value in your regression.fit?

Comment: And are you using scikit-learn?

Comment: The third value passed to `fit` is [the number of jobs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.fit). If you replace `prediction_value` with a `1` there, it may solve your problem. But seeing the full traceback would certainly help to pinpoint the issue, yes...

Comment: @HaochenWu yes i am using scikit. also, i'm getting the same error without the prediction error. here is the traceback:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\uttara\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 682, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\uttara\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 71, in execfile

Comment: exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/uttara/Desktop/MS work/Thesis/code/regression_analysis.py", line 268, in <module>
    result = linear_model_main(Xarr, Yarr, predictionvalue)
  File "C:/Users/uttara/Desktop/MS work/Thesis/code/regression_analysis.py", line 253, in linear_model_main

Comment: regression.fit(X_parameter, Y_parameter, prediction_value)
  File "C:\Users\uttara\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py", line 355, in fit
    X, y, self.fit_intercept, self.normalize, self.copy_X)
  File "C:\Users\uttara\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py", line 104, in center_data
    X_std = np.ones(X.shape[1])
IndexError: tuple index out of range
>>>

Comment: Can you also show us what's your Xarr and Yarr? You could edit your question and put all those information there.

Comment: @HaochenWu done. please let me know if i need to put anything else up here. i'm new to programming and also stackoverflow.

Comment: It's still hard to say what's wrong. After remove the prediction_value from the fit statement it works fine for small test X,Y, so there must be something wrong with your Xarr and Yarr. Maybe you should try your code on the first few rows of your data, if it doesn't work, put a small reproducible error here.

Comment: Just forget to mention, you can use Xarr.shape to see what are the dimensions of Xarr and Yarr. That would be helpful to identify the problem.

Comment: Thanks @HaochenWu. And yes, the program is working properly for small datasets but not for big ones. Anyway, I'll try that and see if it works.

Comment: @HaochenWu both Xarr and Yarr have the same dimension, so that doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: You can try to do a manually binary search on your dataset, that can help you identify where the problem is.